# MS Project Column Time different from Project Time

Tags: ms-project, ms-project-2013

In MS Project 2013 I am attempting to get a particular column to show time unit in Days but leave the default Project Time Unit as minutes for all of the other columns.

I can set the Project default but am looking for a way to change just a single columns time unit.

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by "default Project Time Unit."  I know of no such capitalized term.  My answer assumes you are referring to duration-type task fields.

Answer (score 1):

For a given task the units of duration-type fields are fixed/constant.

To display a duration-type field in units other than the defined units for the task, use a custom text field with a formula like:

Round([Duration]/[Minutes Per Day],2) & " days"

(Replace Duration with whatever other duration-type field you are trying to display.)